# Load the first 30 items in my TextField then loading the rest when click

Tags: actionscript-3, air, sprite

I'm making an AIR app (AS3) with Flash.

I've got this Sprite that's loading items from my database table.

```
function complete(e:Event):void {
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
        for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);
    }
    showList();
}

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {
    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
    var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 25
    listItem.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    listItem.text = item.title;
    listItem.y = 140+ index * 40;
    listItem.width = 100;
    listItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
        showDetails(item);
    });
    list.addChild(listItem);

}

function showList():void {
    list.visible = true;
}
```

I will have more that 200 items that will be loaded. So I'd like to load (or display) the 30 first one, and then click on a button to load/display the 30 next..etc (like "pages").

Any idea how I can do that ?

Comment: mmm... variables and some code?

Comment: This is all the code. The variables are in a php file in a server (products). Do you really need them in order to tell me how to be able to scroll `list`  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function showList():void {
    list.visible = true;
    list.useVirtualLayout="true"
}
```

Comment: list is a Sprite. So apparently I can't do that. (Error 1119)